# Why is std::generate accessible without namespace qualifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, namespaces, clang

Is it normal that this compiles fine?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> buf;
    generate(buf.begin(), buf.end(), []{ return 0; });
}
```

(Note the missing `std::` in front of `generate()`)

Is this behavior documented somewhere? Or did I stumble across a compiler or library bug? Which in my case would be GCC 5.3.0 and Clang 3.8.0 on Linux; both use libstdc++, so maybe library bug?

Comment: [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) maybe?

Comment: AFAIK - yes, this is acceptable, because a type `std::vector` defined within the same namespace (`std`).

Comment: @soon: It's unspecified whether iterator types live in namespace `std`. If the iterator type is just a bare pointer, then that wouldn't work. In particular, the behaviour can depend on whether you compile in debug or optimized mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is allowed, essentially because the arguments to `generate` are in `std`.

Code like

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct B{};
    void foo(const B&);
}

int main()
{
    Foo::B b; /*Requires Foo::*/
    foo(b); /*Does not require Foo:: as that is gleaned from the argument*/
}
```

is acceptable for similar reasons. We call it *argument dependent lookup*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Comment: It isn't guaranteed that the arguments (vector iterators) are in `namespace std`. So this could fail to compile on some platforms/configurations.

Comment: the namespaces of all argument types will be searched for the name `generate` when you call `generate(x, y, f);` The namespaces are taken from the arguments before the function name search starts.